# Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined

Tags: protractor, cucumber, undefined

I'm using protractor to test my app.

I'm trying to get the value inside a tag `<p>` and I can do this as shown by `console.log`, but the expected returns an error:

```
[14:54:57] E/launcher - Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined
[14:54:57] E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined
```

This is my code on `stepdefinitions.js`:

```
Then('I see the alert "Values are incorrect" for the contents which does not match the proper data', function (next) {
    browser.sleep(9999);
    let failed_msg = element(by.css('.error-message'));
    failed_msg.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('MY ALERT MESSAGE FOR THIS SCENARIO IS: ',text);
        expect((failed_msg).to.equal("Values are incorrect"));   
        next();
    });
});
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using this:

```
expect(text.should.be.equal("Values are incorrect"));
```

Thank u the same ;)

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `expect(text).to.equal('Values are incorrect')`, assuming you are using chai.expect